# Graphics3D to three.js converter?

Tags: graphics, export, graphics3d

This question is a duplicate of a [question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7883366/1353714)
But since the answer is 6 years old, things may have changed somewhat.

### Question

> I would like to render Mathematica `Graphics3D` in [three.js](https://threejs.org/examples/).

### Attempt

So far I have used

```
 Export["test.3ds", pl, "3DS"]
```

on  this Mathematica plot.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and I get this ([click to animate](https://3dviewer.horizon-simulation.org/3ds/skl-small.html))
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Together with the [3ds loader](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_3ds) from three.js 
this only works for mesh like objects, not lines or points for instance and it does not scale very well in terms of performance.

Another possibility seems to be the x3d format which may be loadable  using 
[this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-x3d-loader)

We have written a specific three.js code which produces [this](https://3dviewer.horizon-simulation.org/3dclouds/cube_DM_output_00589_smooth05_c0.01.up_graph_points.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Any other efficient alternatives?

It would be great for instance to be able to export mathematica meshes.

### Post Scriptum

Since I have been asked how these lines correspond to the cosmic web,
i.e. where galaxies live in the universe cf this simulation.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am curious what this plot shows (but maybe chat is better for that).

Comment: You can try to use A3dsViewer. Export to the html5 (three.js format)

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use it with a *Mathematica* object?

Comment: if you can export/get *.3ds file from the Mathematica object. Simply do load 3ds file in the A3dsViewer and export to html5(three.js format), it should work.

Comment: Maybe it will work if you replace `Line` by `Tube` and `Point` by `Sphere` (with appropriate radii). As far as I remember, three.js supports also OBJ format and you can export directly to it from Mathematica.

Comment: I have also quite efficient code for turning a `Line` into a `GraphicsComplex` consisting of triangles (with vertex normals). Would that help?

Comment: I wasn't really satisfied with it since it does not really answer the question and it felt pretty much like a code dump... But maybe somebody might find this useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I just dump my code for the function `MyTube`. The function creates a tube around a polygonal line.

This does not really answer the OP's question, but the resulting `GraphicsComplex` 1.) gets rendered more fluently in Mathematica and 2.) can be exported by standard means to other mesh formats (e.g., 3ds, obj, stl...). So, it might become a piece in a more complex export pipeline.

The function `MyTube` employs a (discrete) Bishop frame along the polygonal curve (slightly twisted in case the option `"Closed"` is set to `True` in order to produce a water-tight surface). The code doesn't look very elegant but it does the job and it has decent performance.

```
ClearAll[MyTube]
MyTube[pts_, OptionsPattern[{
    "Radius" -> 0.025,
    "Closed" -> False,
    "InitialVector" -> Automatic,
    Mesh -> 32
    }]] :=

 Module[{p, ν, nn, mm, dp, τ, b, e, ϕ, w, , u, 
   v, τ0, e0, A, a, q, u0, v0, normals, fflist, radius, Alist, 
   closedQ, angles, λ, ω, mostτ, restτ},
  p = pts;
  closedQ = OptionValue["Closed"];
  radius = OptionValue["Radius"];
  nn = OptionValue["Mesh"];
  ν = Transpose[{Cos[#], Sin[#]} &[Most[Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, nn]]]];
  If[closedQ, p = Join[{p[[-2]]}, p, {p[[2]]}], p = p;];
  dp = Differences[p];
  τ = cNormalize3[dp];
  mostτ = Most[τ];
  restτ = Rest[τ];
  If[Length[τ] > 1,
   b = cNormalize3[cCross3[mostτ, restτ]];
   e = cCross3[b, Most[τ]];
   ϕ = cTripleAngle3[mostτ, restτ, b]
   ,
   b = {}; e = {}; ϕ = {};
   ];
  w = NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot[
    rotationMatrix3DAngleVector[0.5 ϕ, b], e/Cos[0.5 ϕ]];
  τ0 = τ[[1]] ;
  u0 = OptionValue["InitialVector"];
  If[u0 === Automatic, u0 = N[IdentityMatrix[3]][[Ordering[Abs[τ[[1]]], 1][[1]]]]; ];
  u0 = Normalize[u0 - τ0 τ0.u0]; v0 = Cross[τ0, u0];
  Alist = If[Length[τ] > 1, rotationMatrix3DAngleVector[ϕ, b], {}];
  If[Length[Alist] >= 1,
   {u, v} = Compile[{{u0, _Real, 1}, {A, _Real, 3}},
      Block[{U = u0}, Join[{u0}, Table[U = A[[i]].U, {i, 1, Length[A]}]]],
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True
      ][{u0, v0}, Alist];
   (* {u,v} is now a Bishop frame. If the curve is closed, 
   we have to twist it a bit in order to get a continuous frame. *)      
    If[closedQ,(*Then*)
    λ = Sqrt[Dot[dp^2, ConstantArray[1., 3]]];
    λ = 0.5 (Most[λ] + Rest[λ]);
    ω = cTripleAngle3[u[[1]], u[[-2]], τ[[1]]];
    angles = ω Join[ConstantArray[0., 1], Accumulate[λ]/Total[Most[λ]]];
    {u, v} = {Cos[angles] u - Sin[angles] v, Sin[angles] u + Cos[angles] v};
    ];
   A = With[{Part = Compile`GetElement},
     Compile[{{u, _Real, 1}, {v, _Real, 1}, {w, _Real, 1}, {e, _Real, 1}, {b, _Real, 1}, {ϕ, _Real}},
       If[ϕ < 10^(-12),
        {u, v},
        {u, v}.Table[e[[i]] w[[j]] + b[[i]] b[[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}] ],
       RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
       Parallelization -> True
       ][u[[1 ;; Length[ϕ]]], v[[1 ;; Length[ϕ]]], 
      w[[1 ;; Length[ϕ]]], e[[1 ;; Length[ϕ]]], 
      b[[1 ;; Length[ϕ]]], ϕ]
     ];
   ,
   {u, v} = Developer`ToPackedArray[{{u0, u0}, {v0, v0}}];
   A = {u, v};
   ];
  normals = Flatten[Table[ν.A[[i]], {i, 1, Length[ϕ]}], 1];
  a = -radius ν;
  q = Flatten[Table[ConstantArray[p[[i + 1]], nn] + a.A[[i]], {i, 1, Length[ϕ]}], 1];
  If[Length[p] == 2, q = {}; u = {u0}; v = {v0}];
  If[closedQ,
   mm = Length[ϕ] - 1;
   q = q[[1 ;; -1 - nn]];
   normals = normals[[1 ;; -2]];
   fflist = Join[
     getOpenTubeFaces[mm, nn],
     ReplaceAll[
      ReplaceAll[
       getOpenTubeFaces[2, nn],
       Dispatch[ Thread[Range[nn] -> Range[1 + (mm - 1) nn, nn + (mm - 1) nn]]]],
      Dispatch[Thread[Range[nn + 1, 2 nn] -> Range[nn]]]
      ]
     ];
   ,
   mm = Length[ϕ] + 2;
   q = Join[ConstantArray[p[[1]], nn] + a.{u[[1]], v[[1]]}, q, ConstantArray[p[[-1]], nn] + a.{u[[-1]], v[[-1]]}];
   normals = Join[ν.{u[[1]], v[[1]]}, normals, ν.{u[[-1]], v[[-1]]}];
   fflist = getOpenTubeFaces[mm, nn];
   ];
  GraphicsComplex[q, Polygon[fflist], VertexNormals -> normals]
  ]

Block[{u, uu, v, vv, w, ww, angle},
  uu = Table[Compile`GetElement[u, i], {i, 1, 3}];
  vv = Table[Compile`GetElement[v, i], {i, 1, 3}];
  ww = Table[Compile`GetElement[w, i], {i, 1, 3}];

  cNormalize3 = With[{code = Sqrt[Total[uu^2]], ϵ = 10^5 $MachineEpsilon},
    Compile[{{u, _Real, 1}},
     Block[{l = code},
      If[l < ϵ, u 0., u/l]
      ],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ];

  cTripleAngle3 = With[{code = ArcTan[uu.vv, Det[{uu, vv, ww}]]},
    Compile[{{u, _Real, 1}, {v, _Real, 1}, {w, _Real, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ];

  rotationMatrix3DAngleVector = With[{
      ϵ = 1. 10^-14,
      r2 = uu.uu,
      id = N[IdentityMatrix[3]],
      code = N[Simplify[ComplexExpand[RotationMatrix[angle, uu]], Compile`GetElement[u, 1] ∈ Reals]] /. Part -> Compile`GetElement
      },
     Compile[{{angle, _Real}, {u, _Real, 1}},
      If[
       Abs[angle] < ϵ || r2 < ϵ,
       id,
       code
       ],
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True,
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ]
     ];
 ];

cCross3 = Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}, {Y, _Real, 1}},
  {
   -Compile`GetElement[X, 3] Compile`GetElement[Y, 2] + Compile`GetElement[X, 2] Compile`GetElement[Y, 3],  Compile`GetElement[X, 3] Compile`GetElement[Y, 1] - Compile`GetElement[X, 1] Compile`GetElement[Y, 3], -Compile`GetElement[X, 2] Compile`GetElement[Y, 1] +  Compile`GetElement[X, 1] Compile`GetElement[Y, 2]
   },
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ];

getOpenTubeFaces = Compile[{{mm, _Integer}, {nn, _Integer}},
   Join[
    Flatten[Join[
      Table[
       {{i + 1 + nn (j - 1), i + nn (j - 1), i + nn j}, {i + 1 + nn (j - 1), i + nn j, i + 1 + nn j}},
       {i, 1, nn - 1}, {j, 1, mm - 1}],
      {Table[{{1 + nn (j - 1), nn + nn (j - 1), nn + nn j}, {1 + nn (j - 1), nn + nn j, 1 + nn j}}, {j, 1, mm - 1}]}
      ], 2]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Here is the obligatory usage example:

```
pts = KnotData["FigureEight", "SpaceCurve"] /@ Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, 2000];
gc = MyTube[pts, "Closed" -> True, "Radius" -> 0.1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Length @@@ Cases[gc, _Polygon, All]
Graphics3D[{Orange, EdgeForm[], Specularity[White, 30], gc}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

> 0.021071
>
> {128000}

[image]

Comment: it looks like this online: https://3dviewer.horizon-simulation.org/3ds/fast-knot.html

Comment: I added, `cCross3`. Looks as if the three.js uses the opposite vertex normals: it renders only the inward side of the faces, not the outward ones... Or maybe something with the export went wrong. The built-in 3D exports are actually rather buggy.

Comment: Thanks, @chris. I guess this is not exactly what you were looking for... =/

Comment: Well I was hoping to stimulate a generic approach for the sake of this site,  but as far as my needs were concerned I was after an efficient tube like solution.

Comment: Okay, then I'm a bit relieved.

Comment: Hey @ChipHurst, thanks for the correction!

Comment: No problem. Nice solution!

Comment: I've noticed a few cases where this fails: `MyTube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}, "Radius" -> .1]` and `MyTube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}, "Radius" -> .1]` are simple cases.

Comment: @ChipHurst Thank you for pointing that out! At least the two errors should be fixed now.

Comment: I notice tubes with sharp bends produce sickle-like features. e.g. `MyTube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {.1, .1, 0}}, "Radius" -> 0.1]`. If I change `e/Cos[0.5 ϕ]` to `e` this seems to fix the issue with no other discernible changes. Do you happen to remember the logic behind this part of the code?

Comment: Hi Greg! Yes I also realized that, of course. I think I wanted to implement miter joints. My main goal was to create nice tubes around rather smooth curves; for them it does not matter. And I think I saw some unpleasant artefacts with plain `e` on the back of the "knee". And miter looks okay-ish up to 90 degrees. (But the surface normals are completely wrong in that case.) Best looking would be rounded joints, but they are so expensive...

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks! Also the radius is not constant just using `e`. For example `Graphics3D[MyTube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {.1, 0.5, 0}}, "Radius" -> 0.1]]` you can see the radius shrink towards the bend.

Comment: Ah, yes! I think that was the reason! =)

Answer (score 8):

I faced with the same issue.
Using Mathematica's function `ExportString[…, "ExpressionJSON"]` I attempted to export the whole tree of graphical functions and wrote a parser in JS.

It was uploaded to GitHub, here is the [link](https://github.com/JerryI/Mathematica-ThreeJS-graphics-engine).

There is a primitive construction with a lot of "switch-case" statements. Each of them implements self function like changing the color or applying a matrix to the group of primitives. After parsing it is rendering to the screen using Three.js library and some part of the code from Mathics project.

**Example**

1. Plot some graphics (used a low-poly mode for smaller code)

```
Graphics3D[{
  SphericalPlot3D[
    2 SphericalHarmonicY[2, 0, t, p], {t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"][[1]],
  Opacity[0.6], 
  Tetrahedron[{{1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}]
  }]
```

[image]

2. Export as a JSON string

```
ExportString[%//N, "ExpressionJSON"]
```

```
[
    "Graphics3D",
    [
        "List",
        [
            "GraphicsComplex",
            [
                "List",
                ["List",
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                    1.2615662610100797
                ]
                ,
                ["List",
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                    1.2615662610100797
                ]
                ,...
```

3. Copy and paste it to data.js

```
\data.js

var JSONThree = [...
```

4. Run index.html

[image]

**Shorter version**

I wrote a figure exporter in `Export2ThreeJS.nb` file. It stores figure and supplementary libraries into a single `.html` autonomous page. Tell me, please, If someone knowns how to insert this function into the native Mathematica's menu.

**Some figures...**

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

PS: It has been helping me to communicate with my colleagues which do not have wolfram software a lot.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is the closest answer to my original question!

Comment: You are welcome, @chris! Hope it will help.

Comment: good job :), it helps me with learning threejs.

Comment: @AsukaMinato, :)) I am very glad to read this

Answer (score 4):

As a teaser, and following up on the example given in the question I can follow the documentation

```
pointcloud = 
  ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "VertexData"];
Graphics3D[Point[RandomSample[pointcloud, 1000]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

make a 3D `ListSurfacePlot3D` out of it

```
pl = ListSurfacePlot3D[pointcloud, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> None, 
  Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and export it a a `3ds` file

```
Export["bunny.3ds", pl]
```

which I can then view in three.js as ([click to animate](https://3dviewer.horizon-simulation.org/3ds/bunny.html))

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this is just one example for meshes.

The corresponding `three.js` code  read

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <title>3DS</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0,\
 maximum-scale=1.0">
                <style>
                        body {
                                font-family: Monospace;
                                background-color: #000;
                                color: #000;
                                margin: 0px;
                                overflow: hidden;
                        }
                        #info {
                                color: #000;
                                position: absolute;
                                top: 10px;
                                width: 100%;
                                text-align: center;
                                z-index: 100;
                                display:block;
                        }
                        #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; \
cursor: pointer }
                </style>
        </head>

        <body>
                <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
                <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
                <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/TDSLoader.js"></script>
 <script>
                        var container, controls;
                        var camera, scene, renderer;
                        init();
                        animate();
                        function init() {
                                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                                document.body.appendChild( container );
                                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.in\
nerHeight, 0.1, 10 );
                                camera.position.z = 2;
                                controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
                                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                                scene.add( new THREE.HemisphereLight() );
                                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 2 );
                                scene.add( directionalLight );
                                var loader = new THREE.TDSLoader( );
                                loader.setPath( './' );
                                loader.load( './bunny.3ds', function ( object ) {
                                        object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                                        } );
                                        scene.add( object );
                                });
                                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                                window.addEventListener( 'resize', resize, false );
                        }
                        function resize() {
                                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                        }
                        function animate() {
                                controls.update();
                                renderer.render( scene, camera );
                                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                        }
                </script>

        </body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, one can also use the `stl`  format for other classes of objects  (which seems to be the default for 3D Printing in Mathematica 11)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Export["contour.3ds", pl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also

```
model = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Triceratops"}, "Region"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Export["contour.3ds", model]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An example of implementation in `three.js` is shown [here](https://3dviewer.horizon-simulation.org/stl/webgl_loader_stl.html)

---

A drawback of `sts` or `3ds`  is that they loose colours.

For instance

```
LeftRightTorus[i_, j_, k_] := 
 0.1 {i + Sin[t] (3.9 + Cos[r]), j + Cos[t] (3.9 + Cos[r]), k + Sin[r]}
FrontBackTorus[i_, j_, k_] := 
 0.1 {i + Sin[r], j + (3.9 + Cos[r]) Sin[t], k + (3.9 + Cos[r]) Cos[t]}
TopBottomTorus[i_, j_, k_] := 
 0.1 {i + (3.9 + Cos[r]) Cos[t], j + Sin[r], k + (3.9 + Cos[r]) Sin[t]}
pl = ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{FrontBackTorus[6, 0, 6], FrontBackTorus[12, 6, 12], 
    FrontBackTorus[12, 6, 0], FrontBackTorus[18, 0, 6], 
    FrontBackTorus[6, 12, 6], FrontBackTorus[18, 12, 6], 
    LeftRightTorus[12, 0, 0], LeftRightTorus[12, 12, 12], 
    LeftRightTorus[6, 6, 6], LeftRightTorus[18, 6, 6], 
    LeftRightTorus[12, 0, 12], LeftRightTorus[12, 12, 0], 
    TopBottomTorus[6, 0, 0], TopBottomTorus[18, 0, 0], 
    TopBottomTorus[6, 0, 12], TopBottomTorus[18, 0, 12], 
    TopBottomTorus[6, 12, 12], TopBottomTorus[18, 12, 12], 
    TopBottomTorus[6, 12, 0], TopBottomTorus[18, 12, 0], 
    TopBottomTorus[12, 6, 6]}], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False
  , PlotStyle -> ColorData[10] /@ Range[10]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
 Export["knot.st", pl]
```

looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

i.e. it has lost the colour information.

Comment: I am afraid, exporting color information correctly in a universal way is rather nontrivial due to the very differering ways color is handled in various languages...

Answer (score -1):

The "WLJS Notebook" project is actively working on it:

- Website: https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/
- GitHub: https://github.com/JerryI/wolfram-js-frontend

Comment: Can you add an example that shows how to solve OP's problem?